# Not able to apply SharePoint Retention Policy

Tags: office-dev-pnp, governance, compliance-center

I am new to SharePoint Online Data Governance and followed below steps

1. Created a new site
2. Created a new Retention Policy with Specific SharePoint site

When I was at step #2 got below error

> No exact match was found. The URL 'https://orgname.sharepoint.com/sites/TestRetentionPolicy' may be invalid, you don't have
>   permission to access this location, or the location is not indexed by
>   Search.

[image]

Comment: if you have created your site just now then wait fro another 24 hrs to index with search and usable to apply retention policy. if site you have created long ago then may be some another issue .need to dig

Comment: @vinitkumar you are correct. I tried it after some time and it worked.

Comment: happy that suggestion helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If the site is a Communication site or a site created from the central admin, you find it in the SharePoint area. If it is a Team site (with inbox annexed) you find it under exchange because it is considered an inbox first and a site second.